# Contribution total amount being doubled when Tax Rate is set to 0 on manual membership renewal

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, taxes

We're running on Drupal 7 and the latest ESR 5.27.5 (was able to replicate on dmaster).

On manual membership renewal with the member dues financial type which has a VAT/GST account attached to it that has 0% tax rate, sets it to pending, the contribution total amount displayed is double the actual contribution total.

I thought this was only on the ESR version but I was able to replicate this on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Steps to replicate:

1. Add a VAT financial account with tax rate 0
2. Add the financial account to the member dues financial type
3. Go to any contact with an active membership.
4. Renew the membership manually and set the status to pending and save. Check the contribution total amount.

**Instead of setting it to pending, if the payment is set to completed, the total amount is correct but the subtotal seen on the invoice is incorrect.**

This only happens when tax rate is set to 0.

If the tax rate is even set to 0.0000001, this does not occur. Thought I would bring this up because I'm assuming it affects a few version.

This is still visible on dmaster if someone wants to check.

[image]

[image: dmaster]

Comment: If your Tax Rate = 0 (so in config you have is Tax = yes but then Tax Rate = 0), why not use a Financial Type that has no Sales Tax associated with it?

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT that seems reasonable but we want to be able to display the price as "€ 150 (includes VAT of € 0)", if we remove the sales tax, it just shows  € 150.000000.

Comment: I meant using a Financial type that has no VAT associated with it at all. I agree it’s a bug but you can get the numbers correct and deal with the display issue differently e.g. in the invoice message template. Using 0% for Tax Rate is an unexpected use case of Tax Rates -> so I’m not surprised something unexpected happens

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading civi to 5.28.4 as it should be fixed in this version

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thanks for your suggestion. Why would I be able to replicate this in dmaster demo site which is on 5.31.alpha1 if it was rectified in 5.28.4?

Comment: Tried upgrading to 5.28.4 - same issue still exists. Not really sure what to try next.